# Python/sqlite3 - Database is locked error on SELECT query

Tags: python, sqlite

I am frequently getting `OperationalError: Database is Locked` on SELECT queries that I am make on sqlite3 DB using Python's sqlite3 module. I have read Python's sqlite3 document and it mentions that we can pass `timeout=N` param to `sqlite3.connect` to specify how long a connection should wait for the lock to go away.

Does sqlite3 raises exception while trying to create a connection object or it is raised when a select is made.

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely right,
Just use timeout to your connection,
but this is not that your database will not lock,
when your database will locked, it will locked for this specific timeout
sample code is

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("mydb", timeout=10)
```

this means whenever database will lock, database will unlocked after 10 milliseconds